# How to increase RAM using a USB as RAM memory?

Tags: linux, usb, memory, performance

I'm using Ubuntu, a Linux distro.

I read some years ago about the possibility to increase the RAM by using a pen-drive USB as additional memory RAM.

I already googled that but I found only articles talking about using pen-drive as additional swap.

There is a way to do this? The pen-drive as swap is the same as additional RAM?

Comment: The swap file is technically acts like RAM... but the speed on USB will be atrociously slow. Are you sure you wanted to do this?

Comment: sure, I bought a 16 GB USB only to do that. My need is to speed up my notebook for at least some months

Comment: Why not use a swapfile on the hard drive? It will be much faster than a USB key.

Comment: Linux doesn't have a hybrid solution like Windows readyboost AFAIK. Note that it's just storing some pages in an external memory, the RAM amount is not increased in any cases

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I thought that using the hard drive it may be compromised or damaged at the long period. So I thought to use a USB because if it'll be broken, I'll lose few money.

Comment: Even the worst SSD has a lifetime much longer than most USB keys.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the USB drive will have much better access time, that's why Windows stores small items that need to be accessed frequently on flash, the remainings will still be on HDD

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Depends on how much you pay for it. If you spend "few money" then there's no way it will keep up with anything from the past 5 years.

Comment: The USB is 3.0 with 130 Mb/s of read or write speed. So, whit it can I increase the speed of my notebook in case of the RAM is entirely in use? The swap option on that USB may solve my problem?

Comment: The swap file does not "technically act like RAM". There is no memory address the CPU can assert that will directly, without intervention from the OS, read or write the contents of the swap file. Not if it's on a hard drive, nor an SSD, nor a USB key.

Answer (score 5):

First run this command to find the name of your pendrive from root access in terminal.

```
fdisk -l
```

For my case my pendrive is `/dev/sdb1`. Make sure you get the right drive name then run this to unmount the drive. Change `/dev/sdb1` to your pendrive name.

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

Then run this to create the swap file on the pendrive.

```
mkswap /dev/sdb1
```

Now to turn on the swap file, run this, remember my pendrive is 2GB so I gave swap 2GB (15000). Give yours according to what yours have.

```
swapon -p 15000 /dev/sdb1
```

Done!
To see whether it worked, type in this command.

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

This is how mine looks like:

[image: This is how mine looks like]

Comment: (1) `-p 15000` is priority, but you connect it to the size of the pendrive somehow. Can you clarify what you mean? (2) Is this a permanent solution? I think it's not (an entry in `/etc/fstab` would be). Either way this should be explicitly stated. (3) Setting the partition type to `0x82` is rather optional, but it helps to keep things tidy, especially if you recommend `fdisk -l` as a general way to determine what device is what.

Comment: I use -p 15000 for me because my drive is 1.9GB and I cannot assign the exact 1.9GB for swap because I need a little space for retention. But if for example you have a 4GB pendrive, you can use -p 37500 so the swap space assigned is dynamic according to what size you have.

Comment: My point is `swapon -p ...` has nothing to do with size (`mkswap -p ...` has).

Comment: It took the whole space of my pen-drive and augmented the existing swap space.

Comment: but... is it effective? do you have some performance test results? I have to ressurect an old machine these days :)